# Dropkick dropdown will not open

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-dropkick

I am having an issue with drop kick. It seems that it does not wan't to open up for me. I have tried my own code to get it working, demo code, and also a tutorials code and it all has the same output, it shows the dropdown fine when it is called but the dropdown will not open up. Does anyone know why this could be happening, and how I could solve it? I am including all of the correct files, and it doesn't matter what example I use it is always the same. Could something be preventing it from opening? I have never had an issue with jquery on this site before.

Comment: Please provide your code indicating what part is not working